# .Formula is producing runtime error 1004 - works for all other strings

Tags: vba, excel

Everything works except for the last `.Formula` for `kcFormula`. It returns a `1004 Runtime Application error`. I am thinking maybe I declared the `kcFormula` as a string and it is too big or I have no idea what I am really doing :D

this is the problem statement:

`Sheets("AML").Range(myRNG).Formula = kcFormula`

```
Sub SharePoint_FormatADDcolS()
Dim myRNG As String
Dim lastROW As Integer
Dim matchFormula As String
Dim kcFormula As String
matchFormula = "=IF(ISNA(Table3[[#This Row],[Status]]=Table3[[#This Row],[Last Status]]),"
matchFormula = matchFormula & """ Status Changed"""
matchFormula = matchFormula & "," & "IF(Table3[[#This Row],[Status]]<>Table3[[#This Row],[Last Status]],"
matchFormula = matchFormula & """ Status Changed""" & "," & """Status Unchanged""" & "))"
kcFormula = "=IF(OR(Table3[[#This Row],[Status]]=" & """Rejected""" & "," & "Table3[[#This Row],[Status]] =" & """Completed""" & "," & "Table3[[#This Row],[Status]]=" & """Not Implemented""" & ")," & """ """ & ",INDEX('AMLLAST'!$1:$1048576,MATCH(Table3[[#This Row],[ID]],'AMLLAST'!$E:$E,0),11)"
lastROW = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count

    With Sheets("AML")
        .ListObjects(1).Name = "Table3"
    End With
Sheets("AML (2)").Name = "AMLLAST"

    With Sheets("AML")
                Range("J1").Select
                Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
                Selection.Copy
                Range("J1").Select
                ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial Format:=3, Link:=1, DisplayAsIcon:=False, _
                IconFileName:=False
            Sheets("AML").Range("C1").EntireColumn.Insert
            Sheets("AML").Range("C1").EntireColumn.Insert
            Sheets("AML").Range("C1") = "Last Status"
            Sheets("AML").Range("D1") = "Match"
            Sheets("AML").Range("K1").EntireColumn.Insert
            Sheets("AML").Range("K1") = "BITOOL - Rating"

        myRNG = "C2:" & "C" & lastROW
                Sheets("AML").Range(myRNG).NumberFormat = "General"
                Sheets("AML").Range(myRNG).Formula = "=INDEX('AMLLAST'!$1:$1048576,MATCH(Table3[[#This Row],[ID]],'AMLLAST'!$E:$E,0),2)"
        myRNG = "D2:" & "D" & lastROW
                Sheets("AML").Range(myRNG).NumberFormat = "General"
                Sheets("AML").Range(myRNG).Formula = matchFormula
        myRNG = "K2:" & "K" & lastROW
                Sheets("AML").Range(myRNG).NumberFormat = "General"
                Sheets("AML").Range(myRNG).Formula = kcFormula

    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a parenthesis at the end.....I haven't tested it in excel, but I'm guessing that's the problem.

Note that for issues like this, the easiest way to resolve them is to debug.print the formula and then paste it into an actual cell.  That way, excel will give you clearer error message that you can resolve.

Comment: THANK the GODS for you! So I am assuming that the error was produced because .Formula detected the string has an error with regard to being a formula?

Comment: also thank you so much for debug.print - any other tips would be great.

Comment: Yes, if you try to put an invalid formula into a cell, it will throw the 1004 error (obviously, this is not the only thing that will throw this error, but if it's being caused by a line that puts a formula into a cell, this is generally the problem).  Another helpful tip is to put "Option Explicit" at the top of your form or module (outside of any Subs/Functions).  This will force you to declare all variables by alerting you to any undeclared variables.  This will be extremely helpful in case of misspellings.

Comment: In addition to Freeman's good suggestion, you could also write the code in an editor that will show you which parentheses match, such as Notepad++ or even writing it directly in Excel before moving it to VBA.

Comment: this might be a stretch. I REALLY NEED something like Notepad++ but I work at a Financial Institution and I am limited to what I can run. Any suggestions?

Comment: Excel will match parentheses if you put it directly in a cell first.  Otherwise, Freeman's approach is a great one.

Comment: It just occurred to me, and I just tested it out. You _can_ format a function in the cell in Excel (as I did in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30081589/2344413)). Use **Alt-Enter** to insert a newline. Now you don't need Notepad, Notepad++ or anything else!  You'll need to adjust column width to be able to read the formula when you __F2__ to edit it, but that's a minor issue.

Comment: Hi Guys! So work supports Notepad++! It looks like it could be very powerful and i look forward to watching some tutorials. I have known VBA for like 30 days now progressing strong from Stackoverflow community! Does anyone have some important tips and trips? Key lessons you have learned; favorite properties... cells() range()?@? you guys are awesome thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

You can improve the readability of that last statement by getting rid of all the concatenation:

```
kcFormula = "=IF(
               OR(Table3[[#This Row],[Status]] = ""Rejected"",
                  Table3[[#This Row],[Status]] = ""Completed"",
                  Table3[[#This Row],[Status]] = ""Not Implemented""
                 ),
              "" "",
              INDEX('AMLLAST'!$1:$1048576,
                    MATCH(Table3[[#This Row],[ID]],'AMLLAST'!$E:$E,0
                         )
                   ,11
                   )"
                 )  <---- this guy is missing! (put him inside the closing " mark
```

Also, when typing up those deeply embedded, complex `IF` statements, I usually paste them into Notepad and break them across multiple lines.
When you do that, you'll notice that you are missing the final closing `)`, as [OpiesDad](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30081257/2344413) pointed out.

Give him the credit for the solution, I just wanted to point out couple of tips for resolving the issue that wouldn't have fit in a comment.

Comment: thank you! I would upvote you if i had the credits! :)